# Dynamic Variables in loop

Tags: loops, go, variables

I'm trying to figure out what the best approach would be to handle variables when looping through a slice.

I have the following bit of code:

```
type Server struct {
    Name string
    Features []string
}


func main() {


    var server1 Server

    server1.Name = "server-abc-1"
    server1.Features = append(server1.Features, "feature1", "feature2", "feature3" )

    subMenuServer1 := systray.AddMenuItem(server1.Name, "Server Menu")

    //Manually adding a menu item
    subMenuFeatureItem1 := subMenuServer1.AddSubMenuItem("feature1", "feature1 description")

    //Creating menu items from looping through slice - Not working
    for i, s := range server1.Features {
        dynamicVariable := subMenuServer1.AddSubMenuItem(s, "test")

    }
}
```

How would I loop through the features slice to dynamically create the menu items? The main problem is I need to generate a dynamic variable of some sort which is not supported in Go. Is there a better why to do things?

I've found people mentioning using hash table instead of dynamic variables. If so what type does the hash table would I need if the value is going to be "subMenuServer1.AddSubMenuItem(s, "test")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating new variables dynamically is almost always a bad idea, even in languages that support it. Go doesn't support it, since it's a statically compiled language.

You're much better off using a map of type `map[string]T`, `T` being the type returned by `AddSubMenuItem`.

Comment: Thank you this pointed me in the right direction. Here is the extract I used:
`var menuMap map[string]*systray.MenuItem`
`menuMap = make(map[string]*systray.MenuItem)`

`for _, s := range server1.Features {`
`variable := subMenuServer1.AddSubMenuItem(s, "test description")`
`menuMap[s] = variable`
`}`

Comment: @Gee1983 If possible please avoid writing long code snippets in comments, they are hard to read, if you need to share the solution you can update the question by including the solution at the bottom. Also consider accepting the question if you find it helpful enough: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers